# grab the data using regular expression

Tags: php

I want to get the content inside this meta tag `<meta content="Rs.55.09" itemprop="price">` or immediately after the meta tag (`<meta content="Rs.55.09" itemprop="price"> Rs.55.09` ) ie  the price of the product is needed.Is there any regular expression to grab the data.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please show us your code, the errors it produces if any and the data you're working on

Comment: Do you have a string containing just that `<meta>` tag, or is it part of a larger document?

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof: I am doing an application in which,when a user search for google apps,it will return the details of app like package id,title,screenshots url and price.I am getting the url of apps.Now i want to grab the content(price,rating etc) of that url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
preg_match('/<meta content=\"(.*?)\" itemprop=\"price\">/i', $data, $matches);
```

However, I'd greatly recommend looking into DOMDocument or another HTML parser, because regex is not recommended for parsing HTML like this.

[Read more about HTML parsers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) or [read more about why not to use regex here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/625231).

Comment: :It is not working.should I use index with $matches like $matches[0].

Comment: `echo $matches[1];`, but with some simple trial and error, you could have found that out yourself...

Comment: @Balu: hu? yes, you should...and maybe you should read up on the regex functions in PHP before using them ;) -> php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php (and follow Jeroens advise regarding the parsers)